# Add image on bar chart dynamically

Tags: jfreechart

I want to draw a pin like the one shown below on a horizontal bar chart. I know we can draw a Arrow using Annotations, But I guess its not possible to draw a pin. Can we add a pin image dynamically or any other suggestions

[Bar chart with Pin http://uploadpie.com/27Qzl](http://uploadpie.com/27Qzl)

Comment: @trashgod yes, I got the line but is it possible to add the triangle as shown in the image above?

Comment: Not to my knowledge.